# What does "restrict background data usage" do in network settings?

Tags: networking, network-manager

In Ubuntu, you can configure Wi-Fi settings and network settings, and you will see this checkbox: "Restrict background data usage":

[image: Screenshot]

Does this stop or reduce updates through APT? What about snap updates? Does it have any other effect? Can application developers make use of this setting?

Answer (score 4):

The checkbox marks the connection profile in NetworkManager as "metered". See `man nm-settings` for the `connection.metered` property.

When NetworkManager activates a device, then it marks the device as metered according to whether the profile indicates it. Note that the profile setting can have 3 values: `yes`, `no` and `unknown`/`default`. The `yes` and `no` cases are clear. For `unknown` NetworkManager will guess whether the  device is metered (for example based on certain DHCP options as Android hotspots set them, or Wi-Fi information elements). That results in the metered status of the activated device to be of yes, no, guess-yes, guess-no, or unknown. Other applications can query that status via NetworkManager's D-Bus API.

There is also a global metered status. That is basically the metered status of the device with the best default route. Which is not always entirely clear, for example if the best IPv4 default route is on another device than the best IPv6 one...

Other applications may now listen to the metered status and restict themself. For example, gnome-software may decide not to download packages when the metered status is yes or guess-yes.

So, no. It doesn't actively restict anything. I think the UI is not namend well. But other applications are welcome to restict themself. It doesn't do anything in NetworkManager itself.

Comment: THANK YOU. With this information I found out the UI in Ubuntu 20.04 is broken and won't let me force disable Metered connection detection. It falsely detects my network is metered. However, nm-connection-editor's UI does allow me to force set the metered connection option to not metered... which fixed my system after toggling the link

Comment: It's possible to make snap not download updates over a metered connection: https://snapcraft.io/blog/how-to-manage-snap-updates

Answer (score 1):

Related to [gnome-control-center](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-control-center/search?q=restrict_data_check&unscoped_q=restrict_data_check). It is to tell Network Manager that the Wi-Fi network is a metered connection.

> Can application developers make use of this setting?

This is to have network manager pick an unmetered over a metered connection when there is a choice between the 2. But an application could be create with this in mind: if a connection should be made at that moment when on a metered connection or to issue a notification about the connection being metered.

> Does this stop or reduce updates through APT? What about span updates?

No and no.

Comment: So it doesn't actually do anything in practise?

Comment: Not that I could find (and I do trust my searching foo ;-) ) Nothing but a switch to prioritize connections.

Comment: It looks like you can configure snap to not download updates over a metered connection: https://snapcraft.io/blog/how-to-manage-snap-updates